# Only display min, max and median (mouseover) box plot

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following code that display by default when the mouse is over:

Title of the trace + [min, max, median q1, q3, upper and lower fence]

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(50), type = "box") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1))

p
```

How do I manage:

- to display only the min, max and median (and not the title of the trace) when doing a mouse over.
- to show only 2 digits after comma in the hoverinfo for those three variables

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make `q1` and `q2` disappear, maybe someone else will help you there. But this removes the title of the trace and reduces the floats to two digits.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(50), type = "box", hoverinfo = "y") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1)) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(hoverformat = '.2f'))
```